# How does two function or two class call each other in python

Tags: python, django, function, class, django-models

I need to use a class attribute value (myClass.name) in a function (myFunction) and inside the class  the function is also invoked which is defined earlier or next to the class. I placed the class first and the function last and vice versa. (test.py is the file name)

I'm trying to use a function inside django model filed.

> I'm surprised Why I can't find solution like such a common thing (at least i think, it should be common). kindly help me to solve this Problem.

Here First function than class:

```
def myFunction():
    myName = myClass.name
    return myName

class myClass:
    name = 'rafi sarker'
    hello = 'Welcome'+ myFunction()

myFunction()
```

Erro in this case:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    class myClass:
  File "test.py", line 7, in myClass
    hello = 'Welcome'+ myFunction()
  File "test.py", line 2, in myFunction
    myName = myClass.name
NameError: name 'myClass' is not defined
```

Here Class first, function last:

```
class myClass:
    name = 'rafi sarker'
    hello = 'Welcome'+ myFunction()

def myFunction():
    myName = myClass.name
    return myName

myFunction()
```

Error in this case:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    class myClass:
  File "test.py", line 4, in myClass
    hello = 'Welcome'+ myFunction()
NameError: name 'myFunction' is not defined
```

**What is the problem? **
** What is the solution?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error in your first example wasn't caused by the call to `myFunction()` at the bottom of the code - it was caused by the `hello = 'Welcome'+ myFunction()` that's inside the class body, which is executed *before* the class definition actually exists.  Code in a class body is not common, if you had put that code in a class method you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jasonharper . I got it! But I still don't know, how to use my custom function for **django model field _default_ value**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case, the function call inside class should not be inside the class body. Instead, make a method inside the class and call whatever function is needed.

```
def myFunction():
    myName = myClass.name
    return myName

class myClass:
    name = 'rafi sarker'

    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = 'Welcome'+ myFunction()

myFunction()
```

Reason behind naming the method `__init__()` is `__init__()` method is called automatically with the class. You can name the method anything else according to python principles. But in this case you must  call the method manually to set the value of `hello`.

The parameter `self` could be of any other name as your wish.

And remember, the function definition must be first. Either `myFunction not defined`
error arises